# Values of multiple range inputs (sliders) won't change

Tags: javascript, html

I need to implement a function which is triggered only when all of range inputs (5 sliders) have a maximum value. I tried to do it like this:

```
let ranges = document.getElementsByClassName('range');

    for (let i = 0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
        ranges[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
        });
        
        let rangeValue = ranges[i].getAttribute('value');
        console.log(rangeValue);
    }
```

The code above is inside a function, which is triggered `onchange` in HTML attribute.

However, when i change first value - nothing happens.

Console log after sliding first slider all the way up:

> (5) 50

Then after sliding second slider all the way up:

> (5) 50

Then after sliding third slider all the way up:

> 50

> 100

> (3) 50

Then after sliding fourth slider all the way up:

> 50

> (2) 100

> (2) 50

Then after sliding final, fifth slider all the way up:

> 50

> (3) 100

> 50

I'd like the values of sliders to change whenever i change them via browser.

My html with sliders:

```
<div class="levers">
                        <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range" disabled onchange="launching()">
                        <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range" disabled onchange="launching()">
                        <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range" disabled onchange="launching()">
                        <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range" disabled onchange="launching()">
                        <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range" disabled onchange="launching()">
                    </div>
```

My script with function triggered `onchange`:

```
function launching() {


    // SPRAWDZANIE CZY GUZIKI SĄ WŁĄCZONE
    let czeks = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    liczba = 0;
    eluwina = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < czeks.length; i++) {
        if (czeks[i].checked) {
            liczba ++;
            console.log(liczba);

        }
    } // KONIEC SPRAWDZANIA GUZIKÓŒ
    // SPRAWDZANIE SLAJDERÓW
    let ranges = document.getElementsByClassName('range');

    for (let i = 0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
        ranges[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
        });

        let rangeValue = ranges[i].getAttribute('value');
        console.log(rangeValue);
    }


}
```

I'm really stuck at this point. I understand that my problem is most certainly very trivial, but i cannot resolve this for the third day straight. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me :).

Comment: From https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343213/what-should-i-do-with-this-users-debugging-questions I understand that _"Please debug my code"_ is off topic for Stack Overflow. Do you have a specific programming question? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Why are you adding event listeners inside the function that's called by `onchange`?

Comment: You have no code that checks for a maximum value.

Comment: What's the point of this: `this.setAttribute('value', this.value);`? Why not just use `ranges[i].value` for `rangeValue`?

Comment: Without event listener, sliders values never updates, the consol.log always displays
>(5) 50 as values of range inputs

Comment: I have code that checks ```if value == 100```
Without ```this.setAttribute('value', this.value);``` the values of range inputs doesn't change ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a `change` event listener inside the `onchange` function. That function already runs when the slider is changed, you should just do what you want there. The way you're doing it, you're adding an event listener the first time, and that event listener won't run until the *next* time the event occurs.

There's no need to use `ranges[i].getAttribute('value')`. That's used for the initial value of the slider. When the user is interacting, you use `ranges[i].value` to get the current value.

```js
function launching() {
  let ranges = document.getElementsByClassName('range');
  if (Array.from(ranges).every(range => range.value == range.getAttribute("max"))) {
    console.log("All ranges are at max");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="levers">
  <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range"  onchange="launching()">
  <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range"  onchange="launching()">
  <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range"  onchange="launching()">
  <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range"  onchange="launching()">
  <input type="range" min="1" value="50" max="100" class="range"  onchange="launching()">
</div>
```